# Rails postgresl using ILIKE with array of values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

How can you query multiple records using ILIKE? When passing in a single value it works but when I pass in an array of values I get an object doesn't support #inspect error

```
users = User.where('address ILIKE ?', ["1", "2"]) # breaks
users = User.where('address ILIKE ?', "2")        # works

error: User Load (6.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (lower(address)='1','2')                                                                      
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

Comment: If closing the answer is wrong, please vote to reopen.

Comment: Alternate to the "duplicate" you could also go with `addresses = ["1","2"]; User.arel_table[:address].matches_any(addresses.map {|e| "%#{e}%"},nil,true)`. This will result in a case insensitive matching using `ILIKE` but the conditions will be joined using `OR`.